# AWS cognitoAuthenticationProvider callback is not executing

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm learning AWS so go easy on me if this is an obvious issue.  My goal is to use the Cognito Authorizer in API Gateway to authenticate my users.  That part works fine. I can get tokens to the front end and back to the api.  What I'm trying to do now is pull some user attributes from the user pool so I can put them in some denormalized fields in Dynamo.  It seems the best way to do that is to pull the user attributes on post (if there's a better way please feel free to answer with that as well), which requires `cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers`. The problem is the callback never executes.  At first I was getting not authorized errors, so I updated the IAM policy, and that went away, now I get the logs outside the callback, but not inside it.

**Snippet**

```
let cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({apiVersion: '2016-04-18'});

   
let sub = event.requestContext.authorizer.claims.sub;
let userpool = event.stageVariables.userpool;

const cogParams = {
 UserPoolId: userpool,
 Filter: "sub=\""+ sub + "\"",
 Limit: 1
};


console.log('listing',JSON.stringify(cogParams));

cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(cogParams, function(err, data) {
    console.info('entered callback');
      if (err) {
          console.log(err, err.stack); }
      else {
          console.log('data',data);
          }
    console.info('end callback');
});

 console.log('listed');
```

**Expected output**

```
listing {...}
entered callback
data {...}
end callback
listed
```

**Actual Output**

```
listing {...}
listed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `await` usage, it seems you are using an [async handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async). Also, according to AWS documentation on [using async/await](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-async-await.html), it's noted that functions that take a callback do not return a promise, you must chain them with the `.promise()` method:

> Most functions that take a callback do not return a promise. Since you only use `await` functions that return a promise, to use the `async/await` pattern you need to chain the `.promise()` method to the end of your call, and remove the callback.

So, in order for the `await` to properly wait for the `listUsers` to execute instead of moving forward, you should update your code to:

**Async handler version**

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event) => { // <-- async handler

    let cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ apiVersion: '2016-04-18' });

    let sub = event.requestContext.authorizer.claims.sub;
    let userpool = event.stageVariables.userpool;

    const cogParams = {
        UserPoolId: userpool,
        Filter: "sub=\"" + sub + "\"",
        Limit: 1
    };

    console.log('listing', JSON.stringify(cogParams));

    // use `await` due to async handler
    let userList = await cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(cogParams, function(err, data) {
        console.info('entered callback');
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        }
        else {
            console.log('data', data);
        }
        console.info('end callback');
    }).promise(); // <-- added the .promise() for the `await`

    console.log('listed', userList); // <-- got the result also on the variable
};
```

Note that the callback was kept to show it executing but, as per AWS documentation suggestion, it can be removed.

If you prefer the callback programming model:

**Non-async handler version**

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = (event) => { // <-- no `async` keyword
    let cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ apiVersion: '2016-04-18' });

    let sub = event.requestContext.authorizer.claims.sub;
    let userpool = event.stageVariables.userpool;
 
    const cogParams = {
        UserPoolId: userpool,
        Filter: "sub=\"" + sub + "\"",
        Limit: 1
    };

    console.log('listing', JSON.stringify(cogParams));

    cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(cogParams, function(err, data) {
        console.info('entered callback');
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        }
        else {
            console.log('data', data);
        }
        console.info('end callback');
    });

    console.log('listed');

};
```

On using the [cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#listUsers-property) method, it might be a bit more correct to use [cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminGetUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminGetUser-property) since you should also have access to the username and you're always retrieving a single user.

Comment: Tried both.  Doesn't seem to matter.  I switched to adminGetUser, which was a better option. Thanks for the suggestion.  Using that I still get exactly the same results using both the callback and AWS.send method.

Comment: With the provided code (using `async/await` and chaining `.promise()`after the method call) you should get the result in the `userList` variable and still get the callback to execute, if provided. If you want to remove the `await` you'll need to remove the `async` from the handler function, to work in non-async mode. Updating answer with full working code for both flavors.

Comment: I went back and checked my code. I was was mixing formats.  As shown in the example here I did need `.promise()`, but also needed a `.then()` to handle the returned payload correctly. Marked as answered.